# Springframework.org is down, how to solve bean missing?

Tags: spring, deployment

I have checked http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/springframework.org.html

This is the error I am getting:

Server returned HTTP response code: 522 for URL: http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

I can not build jars using maven, what alternative do I have for this?